# Supplying the Hessian to optim()

Tags: r, matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have an objective function (a log likelihood), which I want to maximize using R for a vector of inputs (parameters). I have the gradient of the function (i.e. the score vector), and I also happen to know the Hessian of the function.

In Matlab, I can maximize the function easily and the performance is drastically improved by including both the gradient and the Hessian to the minimization using optimset('GradObj', 'on') and optimset('Hessian', 'on'). In particular, the latter makes a huge difference in this case.

However, I want to do this in R. In optim, I can supply the gradient, but as far as I can tell I can only *request* the Hessian.

My question: is there a straight-forward way of inlcuding the Hessian for optimization problems in R, as there is in Matlab?

Comment: I don't think the algorithms built in to `optim()` can make use of the Hessian.  You might take a look at the [optimization task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html), or figure out what optimization algorithm MATLAB is actually using when it incorporates a user-computed Hessian, then search for that ...

Comment: the function `nlm` will let you optimize a function using Newton-type algorithm which uses the hessian.  see `?nlm` for details.